# Adding multiple $<identifier> in filterArray to update a field in nested subdocument

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

Sample JSON:

```
{
    "animalID":"1234" 
    "species" : 
     [
       {
        "speciesID" : "1"
        "speciesName" : "Cannines", 
        "subspecies" : 
          [
            {
             "subspeciesID: "1", 
             "subspeciesName" : "Siberian Husky"
            },
            {
             "subspeciesID: "2", 
             "subspeciesName" : "Labrador"
            }
          ]        
        }
    ]
}
```

If I run this below query in mongodb 4, I am getting the desire result

```
db.animals.update(
                {"animalID":"1234"}, 
                { $set:{"species.$[element].subspecies.$[subspecies].spieceName","German Shepard"}},
                { arrayFilters : [{"element.speciesID":"1"},{"subspecies.subspeciesID":"1"} ] } 
                )
```

I am using spring boot 2.2.0.M4. I am trying to achieve the same in springboot application but with no luck

```
Update update = new Update();

             update.set(species+"$[element]"+subspecies+"$[subspecies]"+spicemenName,"German Shepard")
      .filterArray(Criteria.where("element.spiciesID").is("1")
                        .andOperator(Criteria.wher("subspicies.subspeciesID").is("1")))

 mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), Animal.class);
```

I am not sure on how to pass two identifiers in filterArray.

If I pass using andOpertor I am getting an error:

> Error parsing array filter :: caused by :: Expected a single top-level field name, found 'element' and 'subspecies'' on server localhost:27017

Could anyone please let me know what I am missing here.

Comment: @pankaj, can you share how you solved it

Comment: @MeenaChaudhary I couldn't do it with findAndModify. I did it through findOneAndUpdate https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Comment: Im facing the same problem, couldn't you find any solution for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can chain multiple `filterArray()` statements

```
Update update = new Update();
update.set(species+"$[element]"+subspecies+"$[subspecies]"+spicemenName,"German Shepard")
                      .filterArray(Criteria.where("element.spiciesID").is("1"))
                      .filterArray(Criteria.where("subspicies.subspeciesID").is("1"))
                         
            mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), Animal.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Update update = new Update();
update.set(species+"$[element]"+subspecies+"$[subspecies]"+spicemenName,"German Shepard")
  .filterArray(Criteria.where("element.spiciesID").is("1"))
  .filterArray(Criteria.where("subspicies.subspeciesID").is("1"))
                         
mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, update, new FindAndModifyOptions().returnNew(true), Animal.class);
```

Metodo acima não funciona :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.